# list length + list concatenate on uneven lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
list = [[11, 12, 13, 14] [15, 16, 17]]
```

I want to measure the length of each sublist

```
t=[]
for item in list[0]:
    t.append(len(item))
```

Now I want to create a matching list of lists that will consists of string "Point" and a number from list length previously measured:

```
new_list=[]

new_list = "Point" += (x)

for i in t:
    x = i+1
    new_list.append (("Point" += (x) += "="))
```

I hope to end up with a list of lists that will look like this

```
new_list = [[Point 1, Point 2, Point 3, Point 4][Point 1, Point 2, point 3 ]]
```

How would i put that together properly?

Thank you,

Konrad

Comment: Don't name a list `list` because you overwrite Python's list constructor...

Comment: You've completely changed the question now, making a count object -- whether manual or `itertools.count` -- entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate way is to use a count class:

```
class Count(object):
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.count=start

    def __call__(self):
        self.count+=1
        return self.count

c=Count()        
li = [[11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
print([['Point %i = %i' % (c(),e) for e in sl] for sl in li])  
# [['Point 1 = 11', 'Point 2 = 12', 'Point 3 = 13', 'Point 4 = 14'], ['Point 5 = 15', 'Point 6 = 16', 'Point 7 = 17']]
```

With your update:

```
print [['Point %i' % (i) for i, e in enumerate(sl, 1)] for sl in li] 
# [['Point 1', 'Point 2', 'Point 3', 'Point 4'], ['Point 1', 'Point 2', 'Point 3']]
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. previous answers didnt work since i didnt have the intertools module. I was getting errors on import intertools.

Comment: What environment do you have? The itertools module is part of the standard distribution.

Comment: what if i wanted to print just the Point (x). Basically measure the sublist length and print a list of Point (x) corresponding to its length.

Comment: Do you mean `[[4], [3]]` or `[['Point 1', 'Point 2', 'Point 3', 'Point 4'], ['Point 5', 'Point 6', 'Point 7']]`?

Comment: the later. [['Point 1', 'Point 2', ..]

Comment: Just eliminate the second part: `print([['Point %i' % c() for _ in sl] for sl in li])`

Comment: @user3263488 it is called `itertools`, not intertools

Comment: to answer your previous comment about what environment i am in. I am actually using something called Dynamo. It's part of architectural software called Revit. It supports Python script so I am trying to do some operations on lists of XYZ coordinates.

Comment: Does it have `itertools` (note corrected spelling of the module)?  (Great catch koffein)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way using [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) and a nested [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> lis =  [[11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
>>> c = count(1)
>>> [['Point {} = {}'.format(next(c), y) for y in x] for x in lis]
[['Point 1 = 11', 'Point 2 = 12', 'Point 3 = 13', 'Point 4 = 14'], ['Point 5 = 15', 'Point 6 = 16', 'Point 7 = 17']]
```

**Update:**

Use `enumerate` instead of `itertools.count` to get a new counter for each sublist:

```
>>> [['Point {} = {}'.format(i, y) for i, y in enumerate(x, 1)] for x in lis]
[['Point 1 = 11', 'Point 2 = 12', 'Point 3 = 13', 'Point 4 = 14'], ['Point 1 = 15', 'Point 2 = 16', 'Point 3 = 17']]
```

Comment: this is great! I forgot to mention that i wanted it to restart the numbering for every sublist as to get [[point 1, point 2, point 3, point 4][point 1, point 2, point 3]]

Comment: @user3263488 Not my fault, you posted the incorrect output. By the way I've updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to measure the length of each sublist

Instead of using a loop and an append, preferred way is to use a List Comprehension or a map.

```
lst = [[11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
map(len, lst)
```

> Now I want to create a matching list of lists that will consists of
>   string "Point" and a number from list length previously measured:

Actually, you don;t need to calculate the length of each sublist separately. Instead (as your list structure is consistent and known), create a nested list comprehension and use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) along with a counter ([itertools.count](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)) to recreate the list in the format you desire.

**Implementation**

```
>>> lst = [[11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
>>> from itertools import count
>>> cnt = count(1)
>>> pprint.pprint([["Point {} = {}".format(next(cnt), e)
            for e in sublist] for sublist in lst])
```

**Output**

```
[['Point 0 = 11', 'Point 1 = 12', 'Point 2 = 13', 'Point 3 = 14'],
```

['Point 4 = 15', 'Point 5 = 16', 'Point 6 = 17']]

Comment: Beat you to it, BTW you need `count(1)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I see now. Close Call. Let me think of a different answer else I will delete it